# Chrome Extension - injecting javascript fails after download

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, download

I am trying to download a series of files on a website using a Chrome Extension. However, after the first download, the javascript injection fails to work.

The following code is a stripped down version of the extension, that downloads a file from this page:

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/file/word_clock/

The manifest.json file:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "File downloader",
  "description": "File downloader",
  "version": "1.0",


  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

The popup.html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File downloader</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
File downloader

  </body>
</html>
```

The popup.js file:

```
function printamessagelater() {
    console.log("Executed after download initiated");
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('Executed after download initiated');"});
}

console.log("Starting");
chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('Starting');"});

javascriptinjection = "document.evaluate(" + String.fromCharCode(34) + "//a[text()='word clock.xlsm']" + String.fromCharCode(34) + ",document,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.click();";

chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: javascriptinjection});

setTimeout(function(){printamessagelater()}, 2000);
```

The behavior I am seeing is that the `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: "console.log('Executed after download initiated');"});` line does not result in anything printed to the console of the page.

My guess is that the download somehow changes the focus/context/execution environment (something I don't really understand) and hence the javascript is not being injected.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts? It might allow you to get the desired result as it shouldn't loose "focus/context/execution" as you say

Comment: @jbaldwin I've tried, but for other reasons in the full version I need to work with injections rather than content scripts (note that the terminology is a little loose, as the article seems to suggest programmatic injection is a form of content script)

Comment: Programmatic injection is indeed a form of a content script. Have you looked at the right place for the console? See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging#inspect-popup

Comment: @RobW I think so, the log of "Starting" to both the extension console and the page console can be seen. However the log of "Executed after download initiated" can only be seen on the extension console, and not the page console.